# Identifying control types (Static, Button, Gropbox etc.) when extending controls

Tags: mfc

I am extending a few controls on MFC to be used in multiple applications. I have a derived class to extend labels and groupboxes alike, since they are both static labels and only required draw operation.

In my derived `class Label : public CWnd`, I have properly written the `OnEraseBkgnd` and `OnPaint` msg handlers. Everything works well with Labels and groupboxed, I don't mind drawing everything myself.

My question is, from this derived class' perspective, how do I determine if I am a static label or a group box?

I could of course add a member variable or function to indicate control type, set it somewhere in the beginning of the application, and check it and draw accordingly. But I would like to solve this in the extended class's code, not on application code.

Note: I have tried `GetStyle()` and checking `BS_GROUPBOX`, it does not help, since some combination of static styles `SS_*` can be same as `BS_GROUPBOX`.

Comment: [GetClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx).

Comment: That is very promising, but unfortunately it does not directly help me. `GetClassName` returns "button" for a groupbox. I wanted to get the GROUPBOX text like it is defined in the resource file.

Comment: You already know how to tell a pushbutton and a group box apart. You needed help discerning button controls and static controls, and `GetClassName` does just that. Sometimes you have to put two LEGO® pieces together. The resource file statements are an artifact of the resource definition syntax. The keywords are gone, once the resource compiler is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style attributes from `GetStyle()` are different for each control class.  After determining that it is a static, looking at the its style will help decide what type of static it is.

Since a group box is a button, you will need to check for a BUTTON class class with a style of `BS_GROUPBOX`.

One thing to keep in mind, a button's style uses the lower 4 bits to determine type.  Use `BS_TYPEMASK` to get just the button style.

```
if ( (GetStyle() & BS_TYPEMASK) == BS_GROUPBOX ) {
   // etc
}
```